# Make image in table only take up needed space

Tags: html

When I create a HTML table like shown below, the image will take up more space than it needs. Is there a way to prevent that?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/1499/1000" width="10%"></td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying: *"the image will take up more space than it needs"*?

Comment: Yes, nice question. Btw, this happens only if you resize big image.... with smaller ones, space is calculated correctly... One way could be to set fixed image width: https://jsfiddle.net/fgmn8x42/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to the `img` tag in your css

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/1499/1000" width="10%"></td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply a width to "td" if you mean the width of center "td" and apply

```
img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

let's say we are applying a width 10% or 100px to "td" like

```
.td-class {
   width: 100px;
 }
```

we will got our desired results.